# Decoupling ASP .NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in an old project (web forms). I'm adding a new module to the system. Specifically, enable and disable roles massively.

In the web form `RoleAssignment`, I have methods that differ depending on the operation to be performed (enable or disable). So, I'm using `switch-case` and `if-else` blocks to know what type of operation is selected.

I would like to decouple that functionality to not use `switch-case` blocks.

Well, what I've tried is create a class `Operation` that has methods like `LoadUsers()`, `ExecuteAction()`, etc. Then, two classes `Enabling` and `Disabling` that inherit from `Operation` like this:

```
public abstract class Operation : RoleAssignment
{
    public abstract void LoadUsers();
    public abstract void ExecuteAction();
}

public class Enabling: Operation
{
    protected void LoadUsers()
    {
        //Calling sp that load users who don't have the selected role 
    }

    protected void ExecuteAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Disabling: Operation
{
    protected void LoadUsers()
    {
        //Calling sp that load users who have the selected role 
    }

    protected void ExecuteAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Currently my web form is (summarized):

```
public partial class RoleAssignment: Page
{       
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadUsers();
    }

    private void LoadUsers()
    {
        //This is what I intend to eliminate
        switch(ddlOperation.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "enable": break;
            case "disable": break;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

I tried change the web form to this, but it didn't work:

```
public partial class RoleAssignment: Page
{       
    private Operation operation;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This would be the only switch-case block that I would use
        switch(ddlOperation.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "enable": operation = new Enabling(); break;
            case "disable": operation = new Disabling(); break;
        }
        LoadUsers();
    }

    private void LoadUsers()
    {
        operation.LoadUsers(); //No need to use switch-case block
    }

    private void ExecuteAction()
    {
        operation.ExecuteAction(); //No need to use switch-case block
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem is when it creates an instance of `Operation`, it creates a new Context of `RoleAsignment` I mean, all variables are `null`.

I don't know if you understand what I want to do and if exist a simple way to solve this.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the: _The problem is when it creates an instance of `Operation`, it creates a new Context of `RoleAsignment` I mean, all variables are null_. From what I see, the `RoleAsignment` creates an instance of `Operation`. Is there a postback involved in the flow?

Comment: @Tasos K Yes, it is. When I run the program and go over the method `LoadUsers()` the gridview is null and all web form controls. The class `Operation` inherits from the wf `RolAsignment` in order to use its gridview and other controls

Comment: Pass your instance/context of `RoleAsignment` into your `Operation` constructor on creation.

Comment: @mxmissile I can pass the `RoleAsignmet` context, but I can't access to the controls because they are `protected`

Comment: Then your going to have to read the values, and pass those to your `Operation`.

Comment: Yes. So far it is the only possible option. I think